# Keras neural network accuracy problem (100% in few epochs)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I'm writing here, hoping to solve a problem, that i had with a neural network, developed in python by using keras.
I'm newer with the deep learning world, and I'm studying the theory and trying to implement some code.

Goal: develop a net that allows me to recognize 2 different words (commands) that i say [in the future them will be used to drive a small robot-car]. Actually, I want only to achieve the identification of "yes/no"

Implementation: i'm trying to implement a binary classification network.
Here is my code:

- i used librosa to convert the audio training and test set in a matrix input with 193 features
- to overcame the possibility of batch normalization problem, i scaled the data, by using the preprocessing package (I saw that effectively that improves and affects performance): i notice that if I don't normalize training, test and data_to_be_anlyzed by using the same normalization, it doesn't work
- I read that keras accept as input that can be both numpy array, so i convert the target y into numpy
- i proceed with the construction of the model, training and test (i know that i'm using methods that actually are deprecated)
- I use one audio to perform another text, because for the future i assume that the net will receive (and judge) one audio at-a-time

```
import support.myutilities as utilNP
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

#READ AND BUILD INPUT
X_si = utilNP.np_array_features_dir('DIRECTORY PATH')
X_no = utilNP.np_array_features_dir('DIRECTORY PATH')
X_tot = np.concatenate((X_si, X_no), axis=0)
# Scale the train set
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_tot)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_tot)


#0=si 1=no
y=[]
for i in range(len(X_si)):
    y.append(0)
for i in range(len(X_no)):
    y.append(1)

Y=np.array(y)

#READ AND BUIL TEST TRAINING SET
X_si_test = utilNP.np_array_features_dir('DIRECTORY PATH')
X_no_test = utilNP.np_array_features_dir('DIRECTORY PATH')
X_tot_test = np.concatenate((X_si_test, X_no_test), axis=0)
# Scale the test set
scaler2 = StandardScaler().fit(X_tot_test)
X_test = scaler2.transform(X_tot_test)

y_test=[]
for i in range(len(X_si_test)):
    y_test.append(0)
for i in range(len(X_no_test)):
    y_test.append(1)
Y_test=np.array(y_test)


###### BUILD MODEL
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=len(X_tot[0]), activation='relu')) #193 features as input
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) #1 output

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X_train, Y, epochs=300, verbose=1)

#test
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy on training data: {}% \n Error on training data: {}'.format(scores[1], 1 - scores[1]))   
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    print('=> %d (expected %d)' % (predictions[i], y_test[i]))
    
    
#TEST WITH A PRACTICAL NEW SOUND: supposed acquired 
file_name = 'PATH AUDIO'
X = utilNP.np_array_features(file_name)
#Normalize according to input data
X_analyze = scaler2.transform(X)

y_analysis=[]
y_analysis.append(1) # i supposed that the audio is the one that return 1

pred_test= model.predict(X_analyze)
scores2 = model.evaluate(X_analyze, np.array(y_analysis), verbose=0)
print('Accuracy on test data: {}% \n Error on test data: {}'.format(scores2[1], 1 - scores2[1]))
```

Problems:

1. accuracy go in 100% in very few epochs. Is real that the training set is not so big (a total of 300 samples, and 40 for test), but this result is clearly wrong. By the way, if I use a number of epochs > 100, the net works well and performs its work good (practically the result of the single case study, is recognized)
2. if the number of epochs is low (20 for example), accuracy still reach 100% after few iterations, but the training is affect by the error in the results (why are not recognized?) and the final prediction wrong. It is not normal: i would expect a low accuracy to justify the wrong answer, but it remains at 100%
3. I test a lot of solution, passing from setting 'training=True/False', and read a lot of answer here and in stack exchange, but I don't solved nothing.

There is something wrong in my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that 100% accuracy is "clearly wrong"?

Comment: Either it means that your code is overtraining or it's completely fine. It's such a simple task that it shouldn't take too long for the network to learn it properly. I don't see a big problem in that happening

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that something was wrong, because decreasing epochs, accuracy still remain 100% but training test fails. Does not accuracy would goes in training at a result <100%? 
Example: for epochs = 10, the result is:
Accuracy on training data: 1.0% 
 Error on training data: 0.0
=> 0 (expected 0)
...
=> 0 (expected 0)
=> 0 (expected 1)
...
=> 0 (expected 1)
but the result is wrong. 
I don’t understand why it says 100% but them makes decision wrong.

Comment: What is the distribution of the NO and YES in your dataset? If the dataset is not balanced it can easily lead to overfitting. Another thing that you can try is to reduce the number of neurons in each layer. I don't know how many samples you have in your dataset, but it can be that your model is too complex and your dataset has a small variance

Comment: Dataset counts 300 samples and test 40. Yes=160, No=140, for testing 20-20. I try to reduce the neuron: thanks

Comment: Decreasing the number of neurons I get worse functioning: in training some predictions fail, however, I still obtain Accuracy on test data: 1.0
  Error on test data: 0.0. I don't understand why that number doesn't change

Comment: You can try including more samples in your dataset, so that the model can learn more real-world instances.